# переход по ссылки при наведении на не , обновляя открытое окно

Tags: javascript, jquery

доброе время суток, задача такая есть ссылки при наведении на них открывается новое окно  `<a target="framename"  onmouseover='window.open(this.href)' href="ссылка"</a>` , но нужно что бы при наведении открылось одно окно а последующие наведения обновляли его

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="framename"  onmouseover='fun()' href="ссылка">Link</a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun(event) {
window.open("https://google.com","game",opener);
}
</script>
```

Вам нужны параметры в window.open() почитать про них вы можете [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)